# HDCP Software Implementation

Tags: video

How to do software implementation of [HDCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection) for Linux ?

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

HDCP was designed in a way that prevent you from doing so. See [defectivebydesign](http://www.defectivebydesign.org/) to learn more.

Comment: And it's not possible to emulate?